# Interop between F# and C# lambdas

Tags: f#, interop, lambda

F# powerpack comes with a set of conversion methods to translate from Func<...> to F# functions, either standard or tupled ones. But is it possible to achieve the opposite: in case you want to call from F# code a C# method that takes Func<...> and want to use native F# lambda expression (e.g. fun x -> some_function_of(x))?

If I send a F# function with a signature 'a -> 'b to a C# method that expects Func then F# compiler generates the following error:

```
This expression was expected to have type Function<'T,'R> but here has type 'T -> 'R
```

I want to stay with F# lambda expressions but to use a translation layer in order to be able to send them as C# Func lambda. Is this achievable?

Comment: For anyone having trouble finding the conversion methods in PowerPack mentioned here, they're in FSharp.PowerPack.Linq, FuncConvertExtensions

Answer (score 40, accepted):

F# provides constructors for all delegate types that take F# values of the corresponding function types.  E.g. in your case you want to use `System.Func<_,_>(fun x -> ...)` which applies the generated constructor of type `('a -> 'b) -> System.Func<'a, 'b>`.

Comment: does this apply to `Expression<Func<_,_>>` also?

Comment: Sometimes it pays to go to the third page of Google results. A++++ would upvote again.