# Convert F# func to Expression<Func<..,..>>

Tags: lambda, casting, f#, c#-to-f#

I have a module with a function with the following signature:

```ml
module Something =
    let someFunc func = // ('TType -> 'TField) -> 'TValue
        ...
```

and inside that function I invoke a function from some external library which has a method with following signature (C#):

```cs
class SomeClass
{
    public ReturnType<TType> SomeMethod<TField>(func: Expression<Func<TType, TField>>) { ... }
}
```

When I try to pass a `'TType -> 'TField` function there I get an error that it isn't convertible to `Expression<Func<'TType, 'TField>>`. I found the following question on StackOverflow: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134475/expressionfunct-bool-from-a-f-func)

But it doesn't resolve my issue (The First answer didn't work, the second one works, but I have to change the signature of my function).

With the second answer I have to change the signature of my function to the following:

```ml
module Something =
    let someFunc func = // Expression<Func<'TType, 'TField>>) -> 'TValue
        ...
```

Add additional class visible for a "client" of my module, which looks like this:

```ml
type ExpressionHelper() =
    static member AsExpression<'TType, 'TField>(e: Expression<Func<'TType, 'TField>>) = e
```

So the final invocation instead looking like this:

```ml
let _ = Something.someFunc (fun (o: SomeType) -> o.someField)
```

looks like that:

```ml
let _ = Something.someFunc (ExpressionHelper.AsExpression (fun (o: SomeType) -> o.SomeField))
```

I don't wanna force the `user` of my module to convert F# function to `Expression<Func<'TType, 'TField>>` explicitly. I wanna do that inside my module, is there some way to achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a value of type `'T1 -> 'T2`, there is no way you can turn it into a value of type `Expression<Func<'T1, 'T2>>`. This is not possible, because the former is a compiled function (a delegate referring to some object and its method), while the latter is a representation of the original source code.

So, you will need to use `Expression<...>` as the type of the argument to make this work (or `Expr`, which is the F# equivalent if you were to use quotations).

However, there are cases in F# where the compiler automatically turns a value created using the lambda function syntax `fun x -> ..` to a value of type `Expression<...>`. It does not do this for arguments of let-bound functions, but it does do this for the arguments of static methods. This means that you can use:

```
open System
open System.Linq.Expressions

type A = 
  static member foo (f:Expression<Func<int, int>>) = 
    f.ToString()

A.foo (fun n -> n + 1)
```

Comment: this is what I was worry about :(. I did what you propose at first (see the bottom of my question). But I wasn't fully happy with that solution. Nevertheless, thanks for the answer, since it isn't possible I'm gonna accept it.

Comment: @MNie Yeah, your `ExpressionHelper.AsExpression` works because it is also a static method - but is there a reason why you cannot make your `Something.someFunc` a static method too? Even if `Something` is a module name, you should be able to define a type with the same name and have the static method there (if you mark the module with the `CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix` attribute)