# How do I write the continuation passing style for this Func call?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, nbuilder

given:

```
open System
open System.Linq.Expressions
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers
open FizzWare.NBuilder

let toLinq (expr: Expr<'a -> 'b>) =
    let linq = LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression expr
    let call = linq :?> MethodCallExpression
    let lambda = call.Arguments.[0] :?> LambdaExpression
    Expression.Lambda<Func<'a,'b>>(lambda.Body, lambda.Parameters)

let inline with'<'a,'b> (f:Expr<'a->'b>) (value:'b) (operable:IOperable<'a>) = 
    let f = toLinq f
    operable.With(f,value)

let size = 20
    let builderList =
        Builder<dbEncounter.ServiceTypes.Patients>.CreateListOfSize(size).All()
        |> with' <@ fun x -> x.PatientID @> 0
        |> with' <@ fun x -> x.ForeignEHRID @> (Nullable 0)
        |> with' <@ fun x -> x.PatientInfoID @> (Nullable 0)
        |> (fun b -> b.With(fun x-> x.PatientGUID <- Nullable (Guid.NewGuid()); x.PatientGUID ))
        |> withf (fun x-> x.PatientGUID <- Nullable (Guid.NewGuid()); x.PatientGUID) // this line doesn't compile as a replacement for the previous line
```

my attempt at writing `withf`:

```
let inline withf<'a,'b> (f:Func<'a,_>) (operable:IOperable<'a>) = 
operable.With(f)
```

the error on attempted usage of `withf` to replace the other option is

[image: Error This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected]

Comment: `Func` is a .NET delegate type, not an F# function type, so you might want to use `(f:'a -> 'b)` as your argument instead and then create a delegate from it within your `withf` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer thanks to @kvb 's other answer to another question

[Interop between F# and C# lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392000/interop-between-f-and-c-sharp-lambdas)

I just need to call the `Func` constructor like so:

```
let inline withf<'a,'b> (f:'a->'b) (operable:IOperable<'a>) = 
    operable.With(Func<'a,'b>(f))
```

so now this works:

```
let makePatients size = 
    let builderList =
        Builder<dbEncounter.ServiceTypes.Patients>.CreateListOfSize(size).All()
        |> with' <@ fun x -> x.PatientID @> 0
        |> with' <@ fun x -> x.ForeignEHRID @> (Nullable 0)
        |> with' <@ fun x -> x.PatientInfoID @> (Nullable 0)
        //|> (fun b -> b.With(fun x-> x.PatientGUID <- Nullable (Guid.NewGuid()); x.PatientGUID ))
        |> withf (fun x-> x.PatientGUID <- Nullable (Guid.NewGuid()); x.PatientGUID)
```