# Discriminated Union of Func and TimeSpan for C#

Tags: lambda, f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

I'm about 2 hours new to F# and am having some trouble figuring out how to declare a discriminated union type that can be either a `Func<DateTime, DateTime, Option<DateTime>, Option<DateTime>>` or `TimeSpan`.

```
namespace Test

open System

type FuncOrTimeSpan = 
  // Should this be written in a different way to be able to take fun (a, b, c) -> ...?
  | Func of Func<DateTime, DateTime, Option<DateTime>, Option<DateTime>>
  | TimeSpan of TimeSpan

module ThingDoer

  let (|ActiveThing|_|) input = Option.Some(1)

  // Do I need to tell this function that I expect it to return FuncOrTimeSpan?
  let ReturnEitherFuncOrTimeSpan input =
    match input with
    | "should return TimeSpan" -> FuncOrTimeSpan.TimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    | ActiveThing number -> FuncOrTimeSpan.Func(fun (a, b, c) -> Option.Some(DateTime.Now))
```

I'm getting yelled at for: *This function takes too many arguments or is used in a context where function is not expected.*

What can I do so that I can pass the lambda to the `FuncOrTimeSpan.Func`?

Also, should I rewrite `Func of Func<DateTime, DateTime, Option<DateTime>` to something like `Func of DateTime -> DateTime -> Option<DateTime> -> Option<DateTime>`? I have no idea what this means and it didn't help when I tried.

I should probably note that I plan on interfacing with this function from C# (but maybe the C# part that should interface with it will be rewritten to F# as well, so solutions breaking interop are still welcome).

Comment: What are you trying to do with ActiveThing?

Comment: `ActiveThing` is okay, it's just an active pattern for the match clause, no problem there. I called it `ActiveThing` because I couldn't recall the name and couldn't find the tab where I read about it. I also rewrote it wrong, it's edited now.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer There is a problem there because that syntax for a partial active patterns is not correct.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Check the edit, I messed up when rewriting the code originally. Visual Studio doesn't complain on the lines with the active pattern.

Comment: It's hard to answer when you keep editing the question and changing important details. Your original question had curried parameters, which caused the error you saw. But now you changed it to tupled parameters. In the current form, the code wouldn't cause this error.

Comment: I am sorry, I think I only changed the wrong syntax used with the active pattern declaration. My problem is that the part `FuncOrTimeSpan.Func(fun (a, b, c) -> Option.Some(DateTime.Now))` doesn't work, because the lambda I give it is not `Func` (I assume), not with the active pattern. I could edit it to not be an active pattern and the error would still be the same.

Comment: Have you seen: [Interop between F# and C# lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392000/interop-between-f-and-c-sharp-lambdas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite difficult to answer this question without knowing what exactly your intention is so a qualitative description of the problem you are trying to solve would be helpful in giving a clear answer, I'll do my best though.

First of all, your type definition should look like this:

```
type FuncOrTimeSpan = 
    | Func of (DateTime -> DateTime -> Option<DateTime> -> Option<DateTime>)
    | TimeSpan of TimeSpan
```

I don't see anything wrong with your current type definition but it's very unusual to write F# functions using `System.Func`.

If you wanted tupled instead of curried arguments, you'd write it like this:

```
type FuncOrTimeSpan = 
    | Func of (DateTime * DateTime * Option<DateTime> -> Option<DateTime>)
    | TimeSpan of TimeSpan
```

While you're learning though, I recommend you stick to the first until you've figured out the differences.  Basically, curried arguments allow convenient partial application while tupled arguments allow convenient grouping of parameters/returns.  See https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/ for more details about currying in F#.

Anyway, going forward with the first type definition, your function would then look like this:

```
let returnEitherFuncOrTimeSpan input =
    match input with
    | "should return TimeSpan" -> TimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
    | ActiveThing number -> Func(fun a b c -> Some(DateTime.Now))
```

I don't know why you'd use this `ActiveThing` partial active pattern since it doesn't do anything.  It simply takes any argument and returns `Some 1` so you might as well just replace this with a wildcard.

```
let returnEitherFuncOrTimeSpan input =
    match input with
    | "should return TimeSpan" -> TimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
    | _ -> Func(fun a b c -> Some(DateTime.Now))
```

This function returns an algebraic data type containing either 1) a timespan of 10 seconds if you give it the string "should return TimeSpan" as an argument or 2) a curried function of type `DateTime -> DateTime -> Option<DateTime> -> Option<DateTime>` (which ultimately returns `DateTime.Now` for any supplied arguments) otherwise.

Comment: Oh, I see where the confusion came from, very sorry about it - the active pattern actually did do things in my original code, I just simplified it for brevity, but I wanted to leave it in in case it had impact on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the curry result to a System.Func

```
  let ReturnEitherFuncOrTimeSpan input =
    match input with
    | "should return TimeSpan" ->
        let timespan =  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)
        FuncOrTimeSpan.TimeSpan(timespan)
    | ActiveThing number -> 
            let curryResult = fun (a : DateTime) (b:DateTime) (c:DateTime option) -> Some(DateTime.Now)
            let funcResult = System.Func<_,_,_,_>(curryResult) 
            FuncOrTimeSpan.Func(funcResult)
```

Comment: If this solves your problem then we need to mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for the reply. I have decided to mark @TheInnerLight's answer, I hope you don't mind it. I found it to provide points which answered some of my question I haven't asked. Also, please do mark the question as duplicate if it is - I didn't find a duplicate one because the lack of domain knowledge prevents me from googling sufficiently, I know none of the terms to look for. :)

Comment: I don't mind at all. We are here to learn. I hope you grow to enjoy F#. This is one of the best places to ask questions for F#. You should take a look that the [F# info tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/f%23/info). The key terms I used for Googling this was `F# expected "Func<" C#` If you consider it a duplicate you can mark it as a duplicate yourself.